# Any free open source Space management software?

Tags: time-management, reservation

I'm looking for a web app to be able to control who is booking the meeting rooms in a small office. Nothing too complicated, just to select the date and time range, to describe the purpose of the meeting so there's a history, maybe to auth with AD, etc...

Currently the booking works by showing up at the meeting room, and if it's empty you take it, and if someone higher in the hierarchy arrives they can kick you out.

I'd appreciate some suggestion to solve this.

Comment: I think outlook has a way to do this built-in, but I'm not exactly sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource scheduler like the php-based [opensource version of BookedScheduler](https://github.com/effgarces/BookedScheduler/)

- resources like rooms can be setup.
- conditions can also be applied to resources.
- it is multi-user
- it has reports to see history, free slots etc.

You can try out a demo of the cloud version [here](http://demo.bookedscheduler.com/Web/index.php).